# 404 Bad request Streamsend API C#

Tags: c#, api

I m trying to add new owner, connecting to streamsend api using c# code.
I am sending the xml as per the documentation: http://app.streamsend.com/docs/api/OwnersController.html

Here is the xml.

```
strbuild.Append("<owner>");
strbuild.AppendLine("<owner-id>" + strOwnerID + " </owner-id>");
strbuild.AppendLine("<owner-name>" + strOwnerName + "</owner-name>");
strbuild.AppendLine("<from-name>" + strFromName + "</from-name>");
strbuild.AppendLine("<from-email-address>" + strEmailAddress + "</from-email-      address>");
strbuild.AppendLine("<from-street-address-1>" + strStreetAddress + "</from-street- address-         1>");
strbuild.AppendLine("<from-street-address-2>" + "XXXYYY" + "</from-street-address-2>");
strbuild.AppendLine("<from-city>" + strFromCity + "</from-city>");
//strbuild.AppendLine("<from-state>" + "VIRGINIA" + "</from-state>");
strbuild.AppendLine("<from-zip>" + strFromZip + "</from-zip>");
strbuild.AppendLine("<from-country>" + strFromCountry + "</from-country");
strbuild.AppendLine("</owner>");
```

The remote server returned an error : `(400) bad request`

What could be wrong. Please reply.

Comment: Is there any information in the response other than the 400 status code?

Comment: Can you add the code for your Post?

Comment: 400 just means that you did something wrong (according to the server). It's impossible to tell what if you do not include all code for the call or use HttpFiddler to trace the actual HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the 422 Unprocessable entity error and 400 bad request error. Seemed like it was semantically erroneous xml and the xml tag was not well formed near

It solved the problem.
I have just added a new owner by sending request to Streamsend api from c# code. Thanks guys for your responses.